# Removing a specific item from state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to remove just one array item from state on click but im having troubles getting this to work. My state looks like this below, and i want to remove one of the datasets on click (for example label 2).

```
state = {
  data: {
    labels: time,
    datasets:[
      {
       "label": "Label 1",
      },
      {
       "label": "Label 2",
      },
      {
       "label": "Label 3",
      },
    ] 
  }
}
```

The actual dataset is A LOT larger and I would usually just redefine the state using setState, but this isnt practical because of the huge data. Is there a way I can just remove this one array item? I've tried creating a function to remove the item as suggested on another post but i can only get it to work for top level keys.

```
removekey = (keyname) => {
        let newState = this.state;
        delete newState[keyname];
        this.setState(newState)
}

this.removekey('data.datasets[1]');
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A couple things:

When you declare `newState`, you're not actually preventing direct state mutation because simply declaring a new variable creates a reference to the state object, not an entirely new one. Try `Array.from(this.state.datasets)`.

You can then set that new array as a replacement for the `datasets` array in your state:
`this.setState({ datasets: newData })`.

If you want to write a function to do this dynamically, I would write one that takes an index and edits the data array directly:

```
removeItem = (index) => {
        let newData = Array.from(this.state.datasets);
        newData.splice(index, 1);
        this.setState({ datasets: newData })
}
```

Comment: `newData.splice(index, 1);`?

Comment: Thank you that was a really great and insightful answer and it worked for me. If I wanted to toggle this data is there an easy way to call it back too?

Comment: Removing the item is a rather permanent action. If you just want to hide/show them but keep them around, you could add a new key on the objects to govern that, or create a new array of indexes for ones which are hidden.